# Mysqli LEFT JOIN count

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, left-join

I am really noob in mysqli so i need help..

Please help me to **convert this mysql to mysqli**...i can't figure it out..

```
$new_mail = mysql_result(
                  mysql_query(
                       "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mail` 
                           LEFT JOIN `contact` ON `mail`.`user_id` = `contact`.`from_id` 
                                              AND `contact`.`user_id` = '$user_id 
                        WHERE `mail`.`from_id` = '$user_id' 
                          AND `mail`.`read` = '0' 
                          AND `mail`.`delete` != '$user_id' 
                          AND `contact`.`ban` != '1'")
               , 0);
if ($new_mail)
    $list[] = '<a href="link">Message - $new_mail </a>'
```

Comment: The query doesn't change, and PLEASE learn about _SQL injection_. Use prepared statements. PDO and MySQLi have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted...tnx anyway :)

```
$new_mail = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mail` LEFT JOIN `contact` ON `mail`.`user_id`=`contact`.`from_id` AND `contact`.`user_id`='$user_id' WHERE `mail`.`from_id`='$user_id' AND `mail`.`obrisano`!='$user_id' AND `contact`.`ban`!='1'"));
```

@ryan i just wanted to convert that mysql query to mysqli,but tnx :)